# How can I make texmaker autocomplete commands that it doesn't already autocomplete?

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

When I write

```
\begin{
```

in texmaker, I want it to suggest `flalign}` as a possible choice for autocompletion. At the moment, texmaker doesn't complete `\begin{flalign}` automatically; as a result, it also doesn't autocomplete `\end{flalign}`.

I've noticed that texmaker fails to autocomplete other commands too... Is there a way to enable autocompletion for those commands in texmaker?

Comment: Did you check the advanced options? TeXstudio has a powerful autocompletion tool and it looks like TeXmaker.

Comment: TeXstudio looks cool too and I have no problems with switching so I'll try that. Does TeXstudio come with a viewer? I liked that feature in TeXmaker!

Comment: Yes, you can use its viewer embedded or in a separated window. Also you can use inverse search and a lot of tools.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the menu, select `User > Customize Completion`. Then add `\begin{flalign}` to the list of commands. You can also specify arguments using `@`, e.g `\foobar{@}`.