# Add biblatex bibliography to structure of document in editor

Tags: biblatex, texmaker, editors

I would like to add a bibliography using `biblatex` to my document, that also shows up at the structure of my document in my editor. Like, when I define a chapter, it will show up there, too. How can I do this?

[image]

Here (red) I would like to have something like "References" (or in my case "Literaturverzeichnis"), so that I can simply click on it when my document is long and Texmaker switches to the part.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

Zitiere Onlinequelle: \cite{ctan,markey}\par
Zitiere Buch: \parencite{companion}\par
Zitiere Artikel: \cite{springer}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Literaturverzeichnis}] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this would be a feature request for the developers of your editor (TeXmaker?). The outline in your editor is not a LaTeX feature and not something `biblatex` or any other package can do something about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify that both TeXmaker and TeXstudio produce the *document structure* outline by direct analysis of the `.tex` source code. No analysis of the `.aux` file is performed (which would give better results in the sense that the outline would resemble the actual TOC, but would require a TeX run and thus risks lagging behind the document source).

---

At least for **TeXstudio** the document structure can be influenced via the `.cwl` file used for autocompletion. Commands marked with `#L0` to `#L5` will appear in the outline (see http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION). So if you marked up `\printbibliography` as `#L1` it should appear as `\chapter` in the outline. Trial and error, however, suggests that this only works properly if the command takes a mandatory argument that contains the title. This is not the case for `\printbibliography`. In my tests the following `.cwl` worked

```
\myprintbibliography{title}#L1
\myprintbibliography[key=value, ...]{title}#L1
```

with this definition of `\myprintbibliography`

```
\newcommand*{\myprintbibliography}[2][]{%
  \printbibliography[#1, title=#2]
}
```

But of course that isn't really a good option.

**TeXmaker** on the other hand has a slightly less extensible auto-complete feature (see for example [How can I make texmaker autocomplete commands that it doesn't already autocomplete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185935/35864)) and does not appear to allow for customisations of the document structure.

---

In any case I suggest you contact the developers of your editor about this. Note that it would require extensive analysis of the document code to accurately determine the level and  title of the bibliography in all cases. The default heading level of `\printbibliography` and the title change between `article`-like classes and `report`/`book`. The `heading` and `title` options can influence this as well. Lastly, a user can always redefine the default bibheadings, changing the heading level and more. Similarly for BibTeX-based `\bibliography`. Usually the document class defines the level of the heading and the title, but this can all be changed by included packages (and sometimes their options).

There is nothing the LaTeX side of things can do about this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I very much appreciate your effort.