# Adding custom command into autocomple

Tags: macros

Can we set autocomplete for custom command in miktex as it auto complete and suggest the  environment when we start typing \begin{} command.

Corrected one-
Can i set autocomplete for custom command in texmaker as it auto complete and suggest the  environment when we start typing \begin{} command.

Comment: It depends on the editor how one can ad custom commands to the auto complete. Which one do you use?

Comment: Oh sorry I wrote miktex instead of texmaker

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185935/134144 might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks  a  lot. Now I can resolve my problem easily.